# How to return only the end/leaf nodes in a Neo4j cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a structure like so:

user-[:talking]->topic-[:categorized_in]->topic[:categorized_in]->topic... etc

Starting at a user, how would I get the furthest away topics they're talking about. Basically this represents the top level categories they are talking about. This is the only way I know to go about doing this, and it returns all of the nodes along the way, not just the leaf nodes.

```
START user=node(1)
MATCH user-[:talking]->x<-[:categorized_in*0..]-y
RETURN distinct y.uuid
```

This is my latest attempt. It seems to work, though I don't know if this is the best way to go about it?:

```
START user=node(1)
MATCH user-[:talking]->x<-[:categorized_in*0..]-y<-[?:pull]-z
WHERE z is null
RETURN distinct y.uuid
```

Comment: Yes, the last query is reasonable. You check the root by NOT having any further outgoing `categorized_in` relationships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is how to do it for anybody interested:

```
START user=node(1)
MATCH user-[:talking]->x<-[:categorized_in*0..]-y<-[?:categorized_in]-z
WHERE z is null
RETURN distinct y.uuid
```

Answer (score 1):

You can now [filter against patterns in the WHERE](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-where.html#where-filter-on-patterns-using-not).

So if you have a newer version of Neo4j, I think the query would look like

```
START user=node(1)
MATCH user-[:talking]->x<-[:categorized_in*0..]-y
WHERE NOT(y<-[:categorized_in]-())
RETURN DISTINCT y.uuid
```